# Sum of this series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e^nx^ne^{-xn}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

What is the sum of this series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^nx^ne^{-xn}$$
I tried using the geometric series sum on 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{ex}{e^x}\right)^n$$ and got $\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{xe}{e^x}}$ but i'm not sure if this is right?

Comment: Your result is fine, subject to the convergence condition that $|{xe\over e^x}|\lt1$.

Comment: And you must add a multiplicative factor $ex/\exp(x)$, as the summation begins at $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to multiply the first term, i.e. the result will be :

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{xe}{e^x}}{1-\dfrac{xe}{e^x}}$$

provided $$\Bigg|\dfrac{xe}{e^x} \Bigg| <1$$

i.e. $$\forall x \in \mathbb R - \{1\} $$

Since at $x=1$, the series becomes $1+1+1+1 \ldots$ which obviously diverges.  Everywhere else, $x < e^{x-1}$

Comment: can you tell me how his result is fine? as $n$ starts from 1, so there must be a multiplicative factor $\dfrac{ex}{e^x}$ with his ans.

Comment: @k.Vijay Really sorry, I just went with the flow andd didn't notice that the sum starts from $n=1$. Now I've corrected.

Answer (score 1):

No, your ans is not right, as $n$ starts from $1$. Follow this:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e^nx^ne^{-xn}&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{ex}{e^x}\right)^n\\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{ex}{e^x}}{1-\dfrac{ex}{e^x}}\hspace{30pt}\text{ as, }\left|\dfrac{ex}{e^x} \right| <1\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{e^x}{ex}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{ex}{e^x-ex}
\end{align*}